# Android Development Always showing on Screen

Tags: java, android

My question is, is there a way to have like a character always showing on screen, whether I'm in the "desktop" or in the messages?

*Note: I'm non-English speaking user; bear with my English*

Comment: what kind of "character"? Let me guess, do you want a widget that always show on-screen, no matter it is in App or in the main screen of Android?

Comment: "desktop" ? you mean home screen?

Comment: yes Raptor that exactly it, i wasnt searching the correct way, sorry for the stupid question guys but you helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, maybe just a wallpaper theme??

like this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper"
```

or you want to create a system overlay window?

if yes, try this answer:
[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)